# Running analysis on identical datasets and extracting coefficients into a table

Tags: r, for-loop, lme4, coefficients

I have 198 unique datasets, all variables in each dataset are identical. I want to conduct the same analysis (see below) on each dataset.
From each conducted analysis, I want to extract the coefficients from the model result and store those in one table. For this, I have written the following code:

```
 one_table <- data.frame() #dataframe I will use to store results in later
for(i in 1:198){
  load(file = paste("Dataset_",i,".RData",sep = "")) #loads a dataset
  Dataset = get(paste0("Dataset_", i)) #renames the loaded Dataset_i to Dataset, important for model below
  model_result = try(summary(lme(A ~ B + C + B*C + D + E, random = ~1|company,na.action=na.omit,
                                 control=lmeControl(opt='optim'),method='REML',
                                 data=Dataset,correlation = corAR1())),silent=TRUE) #model
  coefficients = coef(model_result) #extracts coefficients from model results
  coefficients_df <- as.data.frame(coefficients) #puts coefficients into a table
  one_table <- rbind(one_table, coefficients_df) #updates table with each iteration of i
```

Now, the code works up to dataset number 96, on which I get the following error: `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.` I'm not quite sure on how to proceed, what does this error refer to?

Edit: I think I found the problem. The model does not run on dataset number 97, I get the following error which relates to B*C

```
[1] "Error in logLik.reStruct(object, conLin) : \n  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in logLik.reStruct(object, conLin): NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The B*C error occurred because a variable had been computed wrongly in dataset number 97 - silly mistake!

Note: you can also store model results in a list

```
list.res.H = list()
for(i in 1:198){
  load(file = paste("Dataset_",i,".RData",sep = "")) #loads a dataset
  Dataset = get(paste0("Dataset_", i)) #renames the loaded Dataset_i to Dataset, important for model below
  model_result = try(summary(lme(A ~ B + C + B*C + D + E, random = ~1|company,na.action=na.omit,
                                 control=lmeControl(opt='optim'),method='REML',
                                 data=Dataset,correlation = corAR1())),silent=TRUE) #model
  list.res.H[[i]] = coef(model_result) #extracts coefficients from model results
}
```

Comment: If this has worked, accept as answer, please go through your all questions and accept the provided answers, if resolved.